# How to clearing my user canvas drawing?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, draw

I have this html5 drawing app that draws just fine on the canvas element.  My problem is, I have an img of an eraser and I want the user to be able to click it and it will erase the canvas.  Extra karma points if you can tell me also how to change the stroke color to white.

This is my html:

```
<div id="draw_area">

<canvas id="myCanvas" />
<p>browser sucks, here's links blah blah blah</p>
</canvas>
</div>
```

This is the JS to complement it:

```
    var points = new Array();
var outlineImage = new Image();

function clearCanvas(){
 context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var canvas, context, tool;

        function init() {
            // Find the canvas element.
            canvas = document.getElementById('imageView');
            if (!canvas) {
                alert('Error: I cannot find the canvas element!');
                return;
            }

            if (!canvas.getContext) {
                alert('Error: no canvas.getContext!');
                return;
            }

            // Size the canvas:
            canvas.width = 367;
            canvas.height= 249;

            // Get the 2D canvas context.
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            if (!context) {
                alert('Error: failed to getContext!');
                return;
            }

            // Pencil tool instance.
            tool = new tool_pencil();

            // Attach the mousedown, mousemove and mouseup event listeners.
            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', ev_canvas, false);
        }




        // This painting tool works like a drawing pencil which tracks the mouse
        // movements.
        function tool_pencil() {
            var tool = this;
            this.started = false;

            // This is called when you start holding down the mouse button.
            // This starts the pencil drawing.
            this.mousedown = function (ev) {
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(ev._x, ev._y);
                tool.started = true;
            };

            // This function is called every time you move the mouse. Obviously, it only
            // draws if the tool.started state is set to true (when you are holding down
            // the mouse button).
            this.mousemove = function (ev) {
                if (tool.started) {
                    context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
                    context.stroke();
                }
            };

            // This is called when you release the mouse button.
            this.mouseup = function (ev) {
                if (tool.started) {
                    tool.mousemove(ev);
                    tool.started = false;
                }
            };
        }
        // The general-purpose event handler. This function just determines the mouse
        // position relative to the canvas element.
        function ev_canvas(ev) {
            if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' || navigator.vendor == 'Google Inc.' || navigator.vendor == 'Apple Computer, Inc.') { // IE or Chrome
                ev._x = ev.offsetX;
                ev._y = ev.offsetY;
            } else if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { // Firefox
                ev._x = ev.layerX - this.offsetLeft;
                ev._y = ev.layerY - this.offsetTop;
            } else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) { // Opera
                ev._x = ev.offsetX;
                ev._y = ev.offsetY;
            }
            // Call the event handler of the tool.
            var func = tool[ev.type];
            if (func) {
                func(ev);
            }
            points.push(ev);
        }

        init();

    }, false);
    }
```

I think I need a redraw function, but I don't really know what I'm talking about in regards to this issue.  Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: Your code as it stands cannot be tested or ran: http://jsfiddle.net/M2JwZ/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your background color is white, which is what clearRect will give you, then all you need to do is change the stroke color to white when the user selects the eraser. This can easily be done with

```
context.strokeStyle = 'white';
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#fill-and-stroke-styles for more information about changing colors.

If your eraser image is drawn on the canvas, then you will have to detect the clicking of it in your `mousedown` or `mouseup` event handlers. If it is outside the canvas, then just add a `onclick` function to set the `strokeStyle` when it is clicked. However, if you want the eraser to erase everything then do

```
function clearCanvas(){
  context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
}
```

Comment: the background is actually an img and the canvas is drawing on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `canvas` variable was not available in the scope where `clearCanvas` is called. While there are other ways to fix this, simply do this:

```
function clearContext( ctx ){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
}
```

and pass the context into your function when you call it.

However note that if you context is transformed in any way the above will not clear the entire visible region. To safeguard against this, you may want:

```
function clearContext( ctx ){
  ctx.save();
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: sorry, but do these commands and functions need to be within the if statements?

Comment: @sethhoova You need to learn the basics of JavaScript programming.

Comment: Do you think I'd be here if I didn't know that?  But thanks for the insight, regardless.